# Background url() and linear-gradient() not working on iOS/Safari

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I have a page where i use a background-image in combination with a linear gradient, which works well on every system besides safari on iOS. On iOS it only shows the image but not the gradient.

```
body{
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0;
position: relative;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-blend-mode:multiply;
background: url(../images/struktur2.png),
linear-gradient(
#740100,
#942901 , 
#CE7800 , 
#F89300,
#F8D254,
#FFB860,
#FFE997,
#D2FFFF )
}
```

Anybody know why this isn't working or if there is a workaround?

Comment: Can you create a snippet that we can run to see the problem? You'll have to include a suitable png. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried a test with my own image. It's working fine on IOS 16.1 Safari. What version of IOS are you on?